# Using Web Deploy's appHostConfig to create web site in IIS 6

Tags: deployment, iis-6, msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm having trouble using Web Deploy's [appHostConfig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569080%28WS.10%29.aspx) provider with IIS 6.  I don't see anything in the documentation saying I can't or that I need to install anything extra.

I know what I'm trying to do works in later versions of IIS.  If I run the command below on IIS 7.5 (Windows 7), it creates a copy of the `Default Web Site` that I can see in IIS Manager.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V2\msdeploy.exe"
    -verb:sync
    -source:apphostconfig="Default Web Site"
    -dest:apphostconfig="Created from command line"
```

However, when I try to do the exact same thing on IIS 6 (Windows 2003), I get this message:

> Error: Object of type 'appHostConfig'
>   and path 'Default Web Site' cannot be
>   created.
>
> Error: A command was issued that requires the IIS Configuration System but the system is not available. Make sure you are using a version of IIS that contains the Configuration System.

Can I do this in IIS 6, or do I need to do something differently?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't use appHostConfig in IIS6.

appHostConfig works by directly syncing the applicationHost.config file which governs IIS7.

In IIS 6, this functionality was implemented using the IIS Metabase, instead of a config file based system, so there is no counterpart that the provider can directly copy.  *(This is why you get that error about the 'configuration system')*

For your example, you can likely use `webServer60` provider to achieve the same.

Comment: Thanks, that's kind of what I expected.  I'll definitely look into webServer60, I hadn't noticed that provider before.

Answer (score 5):

For individual sites on IIS6 use the metakey, i.e.

`-source:metakey path="lm/w3svc/71913498"`

Note that on IIS6, it won't include the AppPool config by default. For that you'll need to ...

`add: -enableLink:AppPoolExtension`